# jQuery add class based on html

Tags: jquery, addclass

This is my HTML structure.

```
<a href="www.example.com" rel="group-1" class="project">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/image.png">
</a>
<div class="data">
    <span class="media">http://www.example.com/video.mp4</span>
    <div class="desc">
        <p>asdfs</p>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/link">view link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to attach a class onto the  tag based upon the HTML from the media class (span.media) in its sibling div (div.data)

For example:
The above HTML would attach "video" to the  tag based upon the ".mp4"
If it was `http://www.example.com/image.jpg` or `http://www.example.com/image.png` then it would attach "image" to the class.

Comment: OK, so you've told us what you want to do... now what's your question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: hmm...you're right. When people comes here to ask a question it would be normal to have tried something before

Comment: You guys are right. I should at least try to solve my problem. I did try to target the <a> tag with css attributes but since there was no content selector I came to a dead end. So I posted here to get your responses and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$(".media").addClass(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (~text.indexOf("mp4")) {
        return "video";
    } else if (~text.indexOf("jpg") || ~text.indexOf("png")) {
        return "image";
    }
});
```

using the version of [`.addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) that takes a function (I'm not entirely clear which tag you want to add the class to, but this should get you started in the right direction).

Also uses the [bitwise not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/bitwise_operators) `~` to turn the -1 result of `indexOf` into 0 (a falsey value)

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/NaKW4/

---

If you want to add the class to `div.data`:

```
$(".data").addClass(function() {
    var text = $(this).find(".media").text();
    if (~text.indexOf("mp4")) {
        return "video";
    } else if (~text.indexOf("jpg") || ~text.indexOf("png")) {
        return "image";
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/vKPy2/

Comment: Thank you. I like yours the best because it was the most concise and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to select item with value '$(".media").text() //this will get you the text in span

1.parse from back to front looking for first '/'....

2.get substring from there till end

3.get substring of new string until first instance of '.'

1. use jquery addclass() function to add class to div.data`

Comment: so, do you mean we need regex?

Answer (score 1):

i think this you may want...a general case...not a particular. The script gets the name of the file and set the class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.media').each(function(){
       var content = $(this).html();
       var nr =  content.lastIndexOf('/')
       content = content.substr(nr+1)
       nr = content.indexOf('.')
       content = content.substr(0,nr)
       $(this).parent().addClass(content);


    }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetExtension(filename) {
    var filenameSplit = filename.split('.');
    var fileext = filenameSplit[filenameSplit.length - 1];
    return fileext;
}    

function InjectVideoOrImageClass() {
    var filename = $('.data .media').html();
    if(GetExtension(filename) == 'mp4') {
        $('.data').addClass('video');  
    } 
    else {
        $('.data').addClass('image');  
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    InjectVideoOrImageClass();
    if($('.data').hasClass('video'))
        alert('yes');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion.  Use some arrays to store the extensions you want to test for as well as the resulting classes you want to apply to that div.  Then call a custom function to test what extension is in use and apply the appropriate class via the .addClass() method.  Here's a JS Fiddle you can have a look at to see it all in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/HZnx5/10/

Try changing the extension to 'png' or 'jpg' to see the change.  I added some simple CSS just to illustrate things a bit more clearly.  Best of luck! - Jesse

PS Here's the JS code here for reference:

```
$(function(){
    var mediaExtensions = ['mp4', 'jpg', 'png']; //array of whatever types you want to check against
    var mediaTypes = ['video', 'image']; //array of corresponding classes you want to use
    var dataItem = $('.data'); //a JQ object correseponding to the '.data' element to add the class to

function doClassChange(el) {
  var elItem = $(el); //corresponds to the element you want to add the class to
  var mediaExtension = elItem.find('.media').text().split('.'); //getting the extension
  mediaExtension = mediaExtension[mediaExtension.length - 1];

  var mediaType; //the class we're going to add to the dataItem element
  switch (mediaExtension) {
    case mediaExtensions[0]:
    //mp4
    mediaType = mediaTypes[0]; //video type
    break;
    case mediaExtensions[1]:
    //jpg - same case as png
    case mediaExtensions[2]:
    //png - same as jpg
    mediaType = mediaTypes[1]; //image type
    break;
    default:
    mediaType = 'undefined'; //or whatever other value you'd like to have by default
}
  return mediaType;
}

dataItem.addClass(doClassChange(this)); //adding the class to the dataItem, and calling a function which does all of the logic
});
```